# network issue router configuration

Tags: networking

I have a router with ip 172.19.5.1  and a network interface 172.19.5.2 with mask 255.255.255.248 and I can rich the router from that interface but when I configure another interface(my PC)I can’t rich the router. I have mask 255.255.255.0 and I had proved with the 248 and with different IP address and it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from the information given exactly what your problem is, but make sure you're in the correct IP range for your subnet. You also need to have the same subnet 255.255.255.248 (or /29), not 255.255.255.0 (/24).

Here's the network info for the working 172.19.5.2/29 address.

```
netmask:             255.255.255.248
                     /29
host address range:  172.19.5.1 -> 172.19.5.6
default gateway:     172.19.5.1
network id:          172.19.5.0
broadcast address:   172.19.5.7
```